# Rails link_to tag tag with styled glyphicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to use glyph icons that I have styled in my rails app.

I want to make the icon a link to another page, but can't use the standard bootstrap styling because I have customised the links for my page's style.

I keep getting a keyword class error - does anyone know why?

Thank you.

I have the following link in my view:

```
<li><%= link_to <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>, page_path('messages') %> </li>
```

I also have css as follows:

```
span.glyphicon-comment {
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:auto;
  padding:10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:grey;};
  a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:grey;};
  a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:dark grey;};
  a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:grey;};
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use `"` around the string, also need to call `html_safe` method on it.

```
<%= link_to "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-comment\"></span>".html_safe, page_path('messages') %>
```

but a better and cleaner way would be

```
<%= link_to page_path('messages') do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `a:visited {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:grey;};` on your glyphicon css but *they should be on your link*

Try this:

```
<%= link_to page_path('messages'), class: "comment_link" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
<% end %>
```

and then style your link, if you are using scss then:

```
.comment_link{
  .glyphicon-comment{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  &:hover, &:visited, &:active{
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:transparent; 
    color:dark grey;
  }
}
```