# How can I call a link_to helper method in a block, linking to an image file while using a class as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code is one element of a gallery. The "a href" tag is crucial for making it possible to expand an image by clicking on it. It is important that I have "a href" otherwise the javascript plugin (magnific-popup) won't work.

```
<a href="app/assets/images/1-fullsize.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
    <img src="app/assets/images/1-thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
            </div>
            <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

So far I came up with this:

```
<a href="app/assets/images/1-fullsize.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
    <%= image_tag("1-thumbnail.jpg", alt: "", :class => "img-responsive") %>
    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
            </div>
            <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

So the images are visible but the the expanding of the picture is obviously not working in Rails. I thought about implementing an link_to helper method inside a block. But I have no idea how I can use the link_to helper method, link it to a file and additionally giving it a class inside a block? Is there a different solution? Does someone have any hints? If you need further information just let me know?

**How can I call a link_to helper method in a block, linking to an image file while using a class as well?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails link\_to tag tag with styled glyphicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461903/rails-link-to-tag-tag-with-styled-glyphicon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the `image_path` as second option of `link_to`.

In Example:

```
<%= link_to(image_path("1-fullsize.jpg"), class: "portfolio-box") do %>
    <%= image_tag("1-thumbnail.jpg", alt: "", :class => "img-responsive") %>
    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                Category
            </div>
            <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Thanks allot I could not figure this one out for the last 2 hours... Worked perfectly I had to change <%= end %> to <% end %> otherwise I would get an error ;)