# Turn a link_to into an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to change my "Like" (upvote) link to an image. Right now I have this and it won't display:

```
<td><%= link_to image_tag("thumb.png"), like_review_path(review), method: :post%>[<%=review.get_upvotes.size%>]</td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails link\_to tag tag with styled glyphicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461903/rails-link-to-tag-tag-with-styled-glyphicon)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pass image_tag and class to link_to tag

`<%=link_to( image_tag("thumb.png"), like_review_path(review), method: :post) %>`