# Remote true for a <a>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To define my ajax functions, I normally use a <%= link_to %> to add a remote:true method. But I have a  tag line

```
<a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>/undone" data-method="patch"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>Cancel</a>
```

that I want to run with ajax.

And I cannot change it into a link_to because it's crashing all my design.
So do you know a method to achieve that ?

Comment: `<a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>/undone" data-method="patch"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 10px;" data-remote="true"></i>Cancel</a>` Try this

Comment: Why can't you use `link_to`? It takes a block which can easily style everything https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461903/rails-link-to-tag-tag-with-styled-glyphicon/24461925#24461925

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys !! @Iceman, because when you're using the bootstrap dropdown, you have to use <a> tag instead of link to. If not the style is not working

Comment: @stigGaret: "you have to use `<a>` and not `link_to`" - this can't be true. What link_to does is generating `<a>` tags.

Comment: Well guys, I know all of that, but try to implement a link_to into a bootstrap dropdown, and you will see that the style of the links are changing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remote: true` is just a shortcut for adding the attribute `data-remote="true"`. Add this to your anchor tag and it should have the same effect. E.g.

```
<a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>/undone" data-method="patch" data-remote="true">
```

---

That said - what's stopping you from using `link_to`? You can use it with a block e.g.:

```
<%= link_to undone_posts_path(post.id), remote: true, method: :patch do %>
  <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>
  Cancel
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, @gwcodes, that's exactly what i'm looking for