# Getting an error when trying to get login/out and account icons in Rails, how can I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to convert

```
<!-- application.html.erb -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

into an embedded Ruby HTML file.

The code I have so far is:

```
# app/devise/user/_login_items.html.erb
<% if user_signed_in? %>

    <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
        <%= content_tag(:span => 'test', :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-log-out') %>
        Sign out
    <% end %>


<% else %>

    <%= link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
        <%= content_tag(:span => 'test', :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-log-in') %>
        Log in
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I have the partials set up in `application.html.erb`:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <%= render 'devise/menu/registration_items' %>
    <%= render 'devise/menu/login_items' %>
  </ul>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:span=>"test", :class=>"glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"}:Hash
Did you mean?  to_s
               to_yaml
               to_set
```

and is highlighting

```
<%= content_tag(:span => 'test', :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-log-out') %>
```

I don't know how to fix it, I've tried using the span class as HTML code but that wasn't working either. The original code works in the `application.html.erb` file.

I'm assuming it doesn't know how to convert into a symbol as that's part of Bootstrap.

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>-->
    <%= link_to 'A2Z.ie', home_path, :class => 'navbar-brand' %>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div> 
        </li> --> <!-- Dropdown links not working with partials. -->


        <li class="nav-item">
          <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> -->
          <%= link_to 'Home', home_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Locations', locations_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Departments', departments_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Employees', employees_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Products', products_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Customers', customers_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Payments', payments_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Orders', orders_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <%= render 'devise/menu/registration_items' %>
        <%= render 'devise/menu/login_items' %>
      </ul>
      <!-- <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form> -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p> 

  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you solve your problem?

Comment: No, sadly, I gave up and didn't bother using them

Answer (score 0):

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

You need to structure it like this:

```
<%= content_tag(:span, 'test', :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-log-out') %>
```

Or with the new ruby syntax:

```
<%= content_tag(:span, 'test', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-log-out') %>
```

Comment: That works, but the glyphicon in the span is missing.

Comment: Does that class give icons outside of the content tag?

Comment: Try class: ['glyphicon', 'glyphicon-log-out']

Comment: Or class: %w[glyphicon glyphicon-log-out]

Comment: Both didn't work. The glyphicons are from bootstrap. Do I need to link them or something?

Comment: Do the glyphicons work anywhere? I've not used them for a few years and forget if you need to setup anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461903/rails-link-to-tag-tag-with-styled-glyphicon/24461925 - following that should sort it out for you

Comment: The glyphicons work (first set of code in question) as normal.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You are using [Bootstrap 4.3.x which dropped the usage of Glyphicon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components). You should use FontAwesome like they suggest here. That's why it doesn't work!

You should use this:

```
content_tag(:span, "test", class: ["glyphicon", "glyphicon-log-out"])
```

**UPDATE 2: RAILS 5 & Font Awesome**

Please try this:

Add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css"
integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

to your `application.html.erb` file after the last `stylesheet_link_tag` tag.

And modify the following file like this:

```
# app/devise/user/_login_items.html.erb
<% if user_signed_in? %>

  <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
    <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Sign out
  <% end %>

<% else %>

  <%= link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path, :class => 'nav-link' do %>
    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Log in
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I hope this helps!

PS: Never give up!

Comment: Nope, the glyphicon is still missing.

Comment: Could you post your application.html.erb layout?

Comment: Posted it in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Created images folder

Added the "glyphicon glyphicon-user" and "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" images from examples on getbootstrap.com, used image link in link_to, e.g.

`<%= link_to image_tag("Search.png", :border=>0), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'nav-link' %>`